# How to play any kind of sound in python without using file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I am writing a program which I will send to someone as a single .py file. 
I want to be able to include sound in this program which the person can hear without requiring extra wav/mp3 files as well. Is this possible? I'm open to using external modules, etc, just as long as it can all be included in one file when I send it.

Comment: Have you done any research about this? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to write a good question.

Comment: Yes I have. And I couldn’t find an answer so I’m asking in here now.

Comment: With the `winsound` standard library module, you could encode your audio as a byte string and include it in your python source file, if you absolutely must only include a single file.

Comment: "just as long as it can all be included in one file when I send it." Why do you need this limitation? This is why packaging, and the `pip install` process, exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`winsound` is a standard python library included with all installations for playing audio on Windows systems; therefore, the person to whom you are sending the program will only need to have python installed.

From the [`winsound` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/winsound.html), you can use sounds from the windows registry without any further file dependencies, e.g.:

```
import winsound
# Play Windows exit sound.
winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

Details of sounds common to all Windows 32 registries are available [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_ALIAS). As stated in the docs, most systems have many more sound aliases available.

Alternatively, you could encode your audio file as a byte string and include this in your python module. You can then pass this bytes object to `winsound.PlaySound` to play the audio.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the library **winsound** to include your audio as a string of bytes in your .py file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [playsound](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/). The code is pretty simple:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('/path/to/a/sound/file/you/want/to/play.mp3')
```

Just use the playsound function and send a path to your file as parameter and it will play the sound.

I used this library to make an alarm app for my laptop, and it worked. Good luck!!!

Comment: The OP stated that including additional files, such as ".mp3" files, is not an option.

Comment: @dspencer sounds are inside the OS (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-sound-files/ea5e743d-bc81-4b2e-8e8e-b7028667bce8)